# struts 2: equal symbol expected error

Tags: struts2

I am trying to set the text in a button to either 'Enable' or 'Submit' depending on the value of a action class member(mode). But it is reporting an error which is saying 'equal symbol expected' on the first line. I searched and found that there are questions regarding 'equal symbol expected' error but nothing specific to Struts 2 tags. Neither I could spot any obvious error as missing closing quotes.

It would be nice if anyone can help.

```
<s:set name="submitButtonLabel" value="<s:if test="mode.equals('enable')">Enable</s:if>    <s:else>Submit</s:else>" />


<s:submit value = "%{#submitButtonLabel}" cssClass="btn btn-gray" />
```

Comment: You cannot nest tags like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest tags like that. Write your `<s:if>` inside `<s:set>` tag instead.

```
<s:set name="submitButtonLabel">
  <s:if test="mode.equals('enable')">Enable</s:if>
  <s:else>Submit</s:else>
</s:set>
```

Comment: Didn't remember of that (always use oneliner set), cool ;) +1

Comment: @Aleksandr M Many thanks. That was exactly the error I was making.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<s:submit value="%{mode.equals('enable') ? 'Enable' : 'Submit'}" />
```

Comment: Why `${...}` and not OGNL?

Comment: @Jaiwo99 thanks for the answer. It worked!! only '#' in #mode is not required as mode is an action member variable on value stack.